# Galaxy S4 download stops when screen is off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, downloading, standby

I'm having this problem with my Samsung Galaxy S4.

When ever I download something from the Internet and turn off the screen the download fails as soon as I turn it back on.

I have tried other browsers like Chrome and Dolphin Browser but all stops downloading when the screen turns off/ times out.

It downloads perfectly when the screen is on all throughout the download.

This is a bit of a problem when downloading something big. I am using only 3G.

Comment: This is strange... I would make sure that the `Restrict Background Data` option isn't enabled under Data Usage Settings.

Comment: Does this failure happens right after the screen turns off, or it takes some time? It happens with me because I use apps like "Greenify" and "DS Battery Saver" which  hibernates my "Download Manager" and "browsers".

Comment: please move browser SD card to device memory.then problem solved! ! !

Answer (score 1):

Because you have enabled the
**Restrict Background Data**

Under Settings>Data Usage>[menu]>Restrict back. Data

***Uncheck that option***

As, that option stops all background (when screen is off/slept) data transfer. Making every apps or system apps unable to do data transfers using internet.

Comment: Would you please explain (source) how "Restrict background data" is related to download getting stopped when screen is off?

Comment: @Firelord. Is my answer OK?

Comment: It doesn't stop the download, it just restricts background data usage. It does not STOP the download.